sap.ui.comp.filterbar - Clear of filters works in BAS but not in hosted BSP application
I have a strange behaviour in my UI5-freestyle application.
It is being developed in BAS, with JS, freestyle UI5, and the backend is CDS ala RAP via Eclipse.
If i want to clear all filters inside the filterbar of my orders-table, it works only inside the bas webide.
It does not work, if I navigate using the url of the index.html of the bsp app.
The browser debugging tools do NOT show any exception / error.
The filters are simply not cleared.
Any clue what might cause this ?


I don't know, since when, but the controls invocation of "removeAllSelectedItems() does the job.
